# Perturbative non-renormalizability and viability?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-gravity, perturbation-theory, non-perturbative

Does perturbative non-renormalizability indicate the unviability of the theory if we were to define it non-perturbatively (for example through a lattice discretization of the continuum QFT or other techniques) or is this **exclusively** an inconvenience in applying the much-cherished perturbation theory?

Comment: GR is perhaps the best example of a perturbatively non-renormalizable theory, but it is still used everywhere across several distance scales and is considered a reasonably good theory. We do lack a full, quantum, non-perturbative definition of GR which would be useful at scales greater than Planck.

Answer (score 2):

It does not need to be an issue in a non-perturbative formulation. In fact, this is exploited in [asymptotically safe quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_safety_in_quantum_gravity). I'll briefly sketch the main ideas, but you can find some nice reviews by [Eichhorn](https://doi.org/10.3389/fspas.2018.00047) and [Percacci](https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15020449). Both are under an open-access policy.

Perturbative non-renormalizability can be an issue for two reasons:

1. the couplings might eventually diverge, which could lead to divergences in physical observables;
2. the theory is rendered useless because it ends up with infinitely many parameters which would need to be fixed experimentally. Hence, it can fit any set of data.

A nonperturbative possibility that can solve both issues is the existence of a well-behaved fixed point in the renormalization group flow. Namely, if the couplings flow to a fixed point, they won't diverge, and this is expected to keep the observables finite (this was originally argued by [Weinberg in the late 1970s](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:11506418)). This solves the first issue. As for the second issue, the existence of infinitely many couplings is not problematic if the fixed point is IR attractive for most couplings and we assume the theory *does* flow to the fixed point in the UV. In this case, infinitely many couplings are fixed by the requirement that the theory flows to the fixed point, and only finitely many are left free to be fixed by experiment.

A difficulty in this approach is to know whether there truly is a fixed point in the theory. As explained in the review by Eichhorn, there is reason to believe there actually is such a fixed point for gravity (including many corrections to the Einstein–Hilbert action), but since one always works with a truncated effective action it is difficult to say for sure whether the full quantum theory really has such a fixed point. It is interesting to mention that dimensionality and matter content affect these results. For example, if I recall correctly, the existence of supersymmetry would spoil the existence of a fixed point for gravity, and hence the non-detection of supersymmetric particles at the LHC can be thought of as a test of ASQG (**warning:** I do not know of a specific reference on this comment about SUSY, I heard about it in a lecture a while ago).

Shortly, once you are working non-perturbatively, the fact a theory is perturbatively non-renormalizable might end up not being a problem. It is possible, albeit not assured, that a perturbatively non-renormalizable theory will still be nonperturbatively renormalizable (i.e., there will be a well-behaved fixed point).

For completeness, "asymptotic safety" is a generalization of asymptotic freedom. In asymptotically free theories, the theory flows to a non-interacting fixed point. In an asymptotically safe theory, the theory flows to some fixed point. I don't really recall right now whether the jargon "asymptotically safe" usually assumes as well that the fixed point is well-behaved in the sense I described. Check the references I mentioned to be sure.